# Get Application Users that are in a particular role, in Asp-Identity-core

Tags: asp.net-core-identity

I looking to get a list of users with linq that belong to a role like; something like this:

```
var adminUsers = _context.Users.Where(u => some linq here...));
```

Answer (score 0):

First create a query to find the related userId's then use this query to fetch the users list. Because the first query is not executed yet, only one SQL query will be issued at the end here:

```
public IList<User> GetApplicationUsersInRole(string roleName)
{
  var roleUserIdsQuery = from role in _context.Roles
                         where role.Name == roleName
                         from user in role.Users
                         select user.UserId;
  return _context.Users.Where(applicationUser => 
                                 roleUserIdsQuery.Contains(applicationUser.Id))
                         .ToList();
}
```